# How to parse a OVF file to retrieve information within it?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, virtualization, ovf

I have Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization(RHEV) Virtual Machine definition in ovf format. I would like to know xsd corresponding to the OVF format. So that I can retrieve the pieces of information from it.

What is the right way to retrieve this information?

My plan is - if the xsd exists - convert the xsd database into c++ classes and access it from there.

I appreciate if someone comment on the approach. OR point me to better way.

Thanks.

Comment: The code is open in oVirt, why not look at what RHEV does and implement the same or even reuse the existing code?